# Stored Procedure in SSMS but not on db

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, ssms

The title may be confusing.... sorry 'bout that.

I am using SQL Server 2012 SP1.

I was wondering if it's possible to create a stored procedure, which is only stored locally in SQL Server Management Studio (`SSMS`), but not in the database?

My job involves a lot of debugging on distinct customers, meaning I do the same initial lookup every single time!

```
SELECT _id_ FROM IdTable (NOLOCK) WHERE _givenKey_ = X
```

This query is mandatory, and others are VERY frequent.
Could I create a stored procedure locally, to just:

```
EXEC GetDefaults _givenKey_
```

Comment: I store a lot of procedures and diagnostics in a folder structure I manage separately, it's then very easy to double click the one I need and hit F5.

Comment: A stored procedure is, well, *stored* in the database. You can't have one "outside" of the database. You are looking for something like a "macro" or a "code snippet" feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to store SP outside of database and be able to `EXEC` it.
Whay could help you is this:
[SSMS Toolpack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/).
You can create snippets containing almost any amount of code and call them by typing `<snippetname>+TAB`. 
The other solution would be to use Projects in SSMS (File>New>Project). You can have all frequently used scripts listed on a toolbar and available everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can run the code stored in your local file system:

```
DECLARE @code NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @code=(select cast(BulkColumn AS VARCHAR(MAX)) from openrowset(bulk 'c:\users\.......',SINGLE_BLOB) as sproc)             
EXEC sp_executesql @code
```